# How to remove red warning in a journal template?

Tags: templates, journal-publishing

I am using a LaTeX template provided by an academic journal on their website:

https://www.informs.org/content/view/full/135145

If you run the code, the template includes a red warning at the top of the document about the use of such template. Any suggestions on how to remove this warning? It seems that it is within the code itself because I don't see this text in the code. I am using this design for my assignment submission that will later turned into a journal submission.

Thank you.

Here is the original warning:

> Authors are encouraged to submit new papers to INFORMS journals by
> means of a style le template, which includes the journal title.
> However, use of a template does not certify that the paper has been
> accepted for publication in the named journal. INFORMS journal
> templates are for the exclusive purpose of submitting to an INFORMS
> journal and should not be used to distribute the papers in print or
> online or to submit the papers to another publication.

The code itself is here:

```
\documentclass[msom,blindrev]{informs3} 

\DoubleSpacedXI
\usepackage{natbib}
 \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\BIBand{and}%
\TheoremsNumberedThrough  
\EquationsNumberedThrough  
\begin{document}
\ARTICLEAUTHORS{%
\AUTHOR{Author1}
\AFF{Author1 affiliation, \EMAIL{}, \URL{}}
\AUTHOR{Author2}
\AFF{Author2 affiliation, \EMAIL{}, \URL{}}

}

\ABSTRACT{
Text of your abstract 
}

\KEYWORDS{}
\HISTORY{}

\maketitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Update:

I am not sure that an assumption posted in one of the comments below by cfr holds all the time. I find a plenty of working papers that look like mine but don't have that message. I am attaching screenshots of my paper vs. the other. Although the names of the journals are different, they belong to the same organization and when I try all original codes still have the same red message.

My output:

[image: My output]

Vs. a paper available online:

[image: Paper available online]

Comment: It is telling you that you ought not be using it for that. Admittedly, it would be a whole lot clearer if they simply put it in terms of the licence. Is there a licence? What does it allow?

Comment: You shouldn't use a journal template for something else anyway as it will just create problems and likely give a not-very-nice result. Journal templates are designed to eliminate your control over the output. Unless you are publishing with the journal, that is rarely what you want or need.

Comment: I am not sure if your assumption is 100% correct. There are lots of working papers that don't produce such messages but still look exactly like mine (i.e. raw). Please see an update.

Comment: Of course, that message is very likely removed by the publisher. The message says it is there to emphasize that just because a document looks like one of their articles, that doesn't mean it's actually been accepted/published. I'd suggest using a different document class for now, and switching to the `informs3` class when you are preparing for submission.

Comment: The license of this class explicitly prohibits distributing preprints made with it. The class should only be used for submissions; the annoying red warning will be removed by the copy editors.

Comment: That people do it doesn't mean that they are legally allowed to do so. You shouldn't use this template for anything other than submitting to the journal. Just use a different class while working on the paper and switch to the template when you are ready to submit. (A standard class such as `article` will make this easiest.)